# How to secure ElasticSearch API in Android application?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

So I have implemented `ElasticSearch API` using `Amazon Web Services`. Now as the `Android Application` is currently in testing mode

I am building an `Android Application` where there is one `Search` feature for `user` where I have used `ElasticSearch API` from `Amazon Web Services`. Now the question is how to secure that `API Request`. 
I have so far seen the `policy based authentication, Shield`. I want something of a token based authentication like restful api's. 
Is there something out there for this or a different approach in android application for searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) that will act as an auth [layer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/).

If you are using a server already then you can do something like the image below. If you are hitting ElasticSearch from your Android App then maybe something like this [custom plugin](https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-authbackend-jwt), but I don't know if your provider (AWS) permits the installation of custom plugins.

You can find an interesting conversation on this [thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/end-to-end-security-w-jwt/45994/4). Maybe something that fits your use case will come up.

[image]

Comment: If I find something else I will update my answer. In the meantime if this answers your question don't forget to accept the answer. More importantly, this is a very interesting use case, so please update your question when you've decided, describing your solution. Have fun